# Why does my Android app crash with error GC tried to mark invalid reference?

Tags: android

When stress-testing my Android app on Android 8.0 in cases involving a high degree of memory churn, the app crashes during garbage collection with the message `GC tried to mark invalid reference`.

The app works fine on other versions of Android - what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug in Android 8.0, and has been fixed in the AOSP, but it is currently unknown when this will make it into an Android release.

https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/platform/art/+/430379/

Issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65268761

Comment: We received this error on Android 12. Any thoughts?